# Continuity of $|.|$ in $W^{1,p}_0$

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

please i dont understand this proof

[image]

We suppose that $u\rightarrow u$ on $W^{1,p}_0$ i dont understand why we must use the weak compactness and the uniform convexity of $W^{1,p}_0$ ?

Thank you

Comment: What book is this? (curious)

Comment: It is a paper "Multiplicity results for quasi-linear problems A.Ayoujil, A.R El Amrouss 2008

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $u_n\to u$ in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, it should be proven that $|u_n|\to |u|$ in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Weak compactness is used to obtain a subsequence $\left\{u_{n_k}\right\}$ such that $|u_{n_k}|$ converges weakly to some $z$. You see that this is "almost" what we want. The statement that $|u_n|\to z=|u|$ for the whole sequence can be proven as a exercise, if you're not sure about it (try doing it by contradiction). Since you have only weak convergence, uniform convexity, by means of the second property in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space#Properties), solves this problem and gives you strong convergence.

If you're still not sure about all this, here's an alternative proof for this theorem:

> **Alternative Proof:** Suppose, by contradiction, that the mapping $u\mapsto u^+$ is not continuous. Then we can find a sequence $(u_n)\subseteq W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ such that $u_n\to u$ but $u_n^+$ does not converge to $u^+$. By going to a subsequence if necessary, we can assume that there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
> \Vert u_n^+-u^+\Vert_{W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}\geq \varepsilon\qquad\forall n.\tag{*}
> \end{align*}
>
> Now, we can take a subsequence $v_k=u_{n(k)}$ such that $v_k\to u$ a.e. and $\nabla v_k\to\nabla u$ a.e.. By using the equation
>   $$\nabla v^+(x)=\begin{cases}\nabla v(x)&\text{, if }v(x)>0\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>   which holds a.e. for $v\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$, then its easy to see that $v_n^+\to v^+$ and $\nabla v_n^+\to\nabla v^+$ a.e. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, it follows that $v_n^+\to v^+$ and $\nabla v_n^+\to\nabla v^+$ in $L^p(\Omega)$, which means that $v_n^+\to u^+$ in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. But this contradicts $(*)$ above.
>
> Therefore, $u\mapsto u^+$ is continuous in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Also, since $u^-=(-u)^+$ and $|u|=u^++u^-$ then $u\mapsto u^-$ and $u\mapsto |u|$ are continuous in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$.**QED**

Just a quick observation: All this holds in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ as well.

Comment: but why $|u_n|$converge weakly to  $z$ we can have directly that $|u_n|$ converge weakly to $|u|$ by the continuity of $|.|$ no ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Notice that, in that part, he had already written that "$|u_n|\to|u|$ (strongly) in $L^p(\Omega)$", so in particular $|u_n|\to |u|$ weakly in $L^p(\Omega)$. Then, weak compactness gives a $z$ such that $|u_n|\to z$ weakly in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. But since $W_0^{1,p}\subseteq L^p$, then this implies that $|u_n|\to z$ weakly in $L^p(\Omega)$. The weak topology in $L^p$ is Hausdorff, so $z=|u|$ (a.e.).

Comment: and if $W^{1,p}_0$ becomes the hilbert space $H^1_0$ what's chang in the proof ? thank you

Comment: By definition, $H_0^1=W_0^{1,2}$, so this case is already covered in this result.

Comment: I dont understand how we introduce the $|.|$ ?, we suppose that $u\rightarrow u $ in $W^{1,p}$ how we see that $|u_n|\rightarrow |u| ~\text{in}~ L^p $ ? Thank you

Comment: $u_n\to u$ in $L^p$ implies $|u_n|\to |u|$ by the uniform convexity that was mentioned.

Comment: no befor that it says that : $|u_n|\rightarrow |u|$ in $L^p$ by weak compactness $|u_n|\rightarrow z$ weakly in $W^{1,p}$ i dont understand how we have this from the fact that $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $W^{1,p}$ ? Thank you

Comment: $|u_n|\to z$ weakly just uses the weak compactness, nothing else, and this claim is being made for a subsequence (suppressed in the notation, for convenience).

Comment: @ChristianRemling    i have $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $W^{1,p}$ it implies that $u_n \rightarrow u$ weakly in $W^{1,p}$ i don't see why there existe a subsequence such that $|u_n|\rightarrow w$ weakly ,

Comment: @Vrouvrou $\left\{|u_n|\right\}_n$ is a norm-bounded sequence in the separable reflexive Banach space $W^{1,p}$, so you obtain a convergent subsequence by [Banach-Alaoglu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Sequential_Banach.E2.80.93Alaoglu_theorem).

Comment: @LuizCordeiro please why $|u_n|\rightarrow |u| $in $L^p$ pleaaaaase

Comment: @LuizCordeiro please to use the uniforme converxity we need to have that $||u_n||\rightarrow ||u||$ how to find this please